# .net How to include directory and file relationship in zipfile

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I am using the System.IO.Compression namespace ZipFile and ArchiveFile libraries.  To be as efficient as possible I call the top folder marked for zipping.  CreateFromDirectory will iterate down though subfolders to include those folders and their files.  However, i have some subfolders that are not marked for zipping. What's worse is that those subfolders marked as NOT to be zipped include sub folder that ARE marked to be zipped.     As far as i can see those skipped folders can not be included in the Zipfile.  Which means I loose my folder structure inside the zipfile.   Which makes it harder to restore files back to the original location.

Is there anyway around this ?

Comment: Without adding the parent folder structure of sub folders you want, dont believe it will work. Even if u mark a folder to not zip but ask for a child of that to be in zip, doesnt quite make sense

Answer (score 1):

You can use ZipArchive and manually add files to the zip archive.
The `entryName` is your desired `target\folder\filename.ext`

```
using (var zipFileStream = new FileStream(destinationArchiveFileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zipFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < filesToAdd.Count; i++)
        {
            // filter some files before this, or ignore some files here

            var fileName = filesToAdd[i];
            var entryName = entryNames[i];

            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileName, entryName, compressionLevel);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` calls internally in a loop as well, just that you can filter it here.